# undeclared identifier using class compared to main function

Tags: c++

I want to understand why I receive a syntax error for the same syntax in different code areas.

For example:

```
#include<iostream>

class Grading
{
 public:
    Grading();
    ~Grading();

 private:
    //Here syntax is broken 
    //reason: undeclared Identifier 
    const int studentID = 50;
    int students[studentID];

};

int main() {
    //Here syntax is fine.
    const int studentID = 50;
    int students[studentID];
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Alternativ: `std::array<int,50> students`

Comment: Even better: use std::vector and not a fixed sized array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const int studentID = 50;` should be `static const int studentID = 50;`. Right now you are declaring `studentID` as a non-static class member and it will constructed (and assigned a value 50) only when class instance is constructed while to declare an array compiler requires array size to be known at compile time. Basically your code is equivalent to this:

```
class Grading
{
    public:
    Grading(): studentID(50) {}
    ~Grading();

 private:
    const int studentID;
    int students[studentID];
};
```

If you write `const int studentID = 50;` outside of class scope (in `main` for example) then it would be just a regular constant with a value 50 known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a C++ member array must be a `constexpr` - known at compile time, simple `const` is not enough, since it will be initialized at runtime, when you create an instance of the class.

However, `static const` is enough, since you must initialize it with a constexpr, so the value is known at compile time.

Comment: Is there a reason for it being enough in the main? And not in the class.

Comment: @user8665559 it is a design decision in C++. It is not simple to implement a type whose size depends on a runtime value. Note that `const` _is_ runtime value.

Comment: so is then the "static" keyword not a runtime value?

Comment: If your question is "why is it a syntax error" and not type error or something else, I would guess the answer is: because it is possible, and it fails faster which is good. The downside is the somewhat obscure error message.

Comment: @user8665559 it is initialized before `main()` begins execution, so it is possible to treat this as a compile time constant (with some trickery). But the truth is, I don't know why this is allowed. It's a good question.